# Verify the regression results by GLM?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model

I used GLM to regress my data.
$$Y=X\cdot\beta+\epsilon,$$
where $Y$ is my original data (i.e., a vector of observations), $X$ are the regressors with a column of one appended to the left, $\epsilon$ is the residue.

I then compute my regressed data to be
$$Y_{regressed}[1]=1\cdot\beta[1]+\epsilon[1]\\Y_{regressed}[2]=1\cdot\beta[1]+\epsilon[2]\\...$$

Both  $Y$ and regressors $X$ are all positive. After regression, I end up with $Y_{regressed}$ being negative. I feel this is normal. Am I right?

Is there a way whereby I can check the correctness of my regression?

Comment: What do you mean by "I feel this is normal"? Is the Y-variable always non-negative (e.g. like a count or a survival time, say)? What do you mean by "correctness"? What do you want to use the regression for? Did you do any regression diagnostics? Why use GLM to fit a linear regression?

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the reply! What I meant can boil down to "Is it possible for regressed data to be negative, if Y and X are all positive."

Comment: Do you mean "Is it possible for *fitted values* to be negative if all Y and X are positive?"

Comment: @Glen_b fitted? It should be "Is it possible for *regressed* values to be negative if all Y and X are positive?"

Comment: The term "regressed value" is ambiguous. I was asking you to choose a term that has a well-defined conventional meaning (which fitted value does). If you don't mean fitted value, please define the term 'regressed value' unambiguously (there are several things wrong in your question, so that's no help, hence the question). $\epsilon$ can't be the residuals, since your first equation has the population $\beta$. The next part of your question then seems to imply you know the errors, which I don't think can be true. Please don't conflate errors with residuals, or population slope with fitted slope

Comment: Does your fitted line have no intercept?

Comment: @Glen_b Yeah, true. This is a bad question. I will reformulate it and edit it later. Thanks a lot for pointing these out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question you can answer for yourself. I'll help you.

Let's start with what seems to be an easier question:

*Is it possible for a fitted value to be below the actual data point (i.e. for a residual to be negative)?*

Like so --

[image]

Would you say this could happen?

Now what happens if I add or subtract a particular constant, $c$, from every $y$ value - What happens to the fitted intercept? The slope? What happens to the residuals?

What if I choose that constant to be such that the smallest observation is *just* positive?

Comment: Thank you sir. So it is possible for *some* fitted values to be negative. I notice that the reason why my fitted data are *all* negative is that my mean ($\beta[1]$) is super negative. (You can think of it as: all the data are ~200, and my $\beta[1]$ is ~-600. Therefore, it "drags" all the fitted data down to negative when I do $y_{fitted}=1\cdot\beta[1]+resid.$)

Comment: Your last sentence in that comment still implies that your model has no intercept. Is that correct? It could change the answer. If you gave your data and commands we could no doubt say something more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP doesn't mention any explicit link function, but the predicted values might not have been transformed to be comparable to the response variable.

If you are using R, the correct code for the predicted values would be something like this: `predict(model, type="response")`. I remember my first big project, forecasting count data. I couldn't work out why I had negative predicted counts until I put the `type="response"` argument in.